# Let X be limit point compact. If A is a closed subset of X, does it follow that A is limit point compact?

Tags: general-topology

I saw a proof of this result, but I'am not sure why I do have to show that the limits points of a infinite subset of A must lie in A. Why is not enough to show that every subset infinite of A has a limit point:

Let B be a infinite subset of A, we also have that B is a infinite subset of X and X is limit point compact, then B' is not empty. So we conclude that A is point limit compact.

Thanks.

Comment: It must be shown that $A\cap B'\neq\varnothing$ since it must be shown that $A$ is limit point compact. There you need that $A$ is closed (hence contains $B'$).

Comment: Thank you! But I don't understand why I must have A∩B′≠∅.

Comment: By definition space $X$ is limit point compact if every infinite subset of $X$ has a limit point in $X$. Applying that on subspace $A$ you get: Space $A$ is limit point compact if every infinite subset of $A$ has a limit point **in** $A$. You cannot leave out the part "**in** $A$". That is a bit different if you are dealing with the original space $X$. In that case limit points will *automatically* belong to $X$.

Comment: OOOHHH!! of course!! thank you, thank you!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see $A$ is limit point compact we need to show that every infinite subset of $A$ has a limit point in $A$.

So let $B \subseteq A$ be infinite. As $X$ is limit point compact, there is some $x \in B'$. But then $x \in B' \subseteq A' \subseteq A$; the latter as $A$ is closed. So we are done: $x$ is in $A$ as required.

Comment: got it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Let B be an infinite subset of A. Then B is an infinite subset of X so that B has a limit point x in X, suppose x in not in A, then X\A which is an open nhbd of x by the assumption, which does not intersect with B. So it is a contradiction!

Comment: what does "same" mean?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).